# python: Imported class does not change, when edited, saved and reimported

Tags: class, python-2.7, python-import

I'm new to Python and trying to understand classes. Not sure the following error is coming from the use of my IDE, which is Spyder, or if it is intended behaviour.

I define a class `message` in the file `C:\mydir\class_def.py`. Here is what the file contains:

```
class message:
    def __init__(self,msg1,msg2):
        self.msg1 = msg1
        self.msg2 = msg2
```

I have another script were I want to execute code, called `execute.py`. In this script I import the class and make an instance of the class object. Here is the code from the script `execute.py`:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\mydir')
from class_def import message

message_obj = message('Hello','world')
```

So far no problems!

Then I edit `class_def.py` to the following:

```
class message:
    def __init__(self,msg1):
        self.msg1 = msg1
```

and edit `execute.py` to match the new class, so removing one input to`message`:

```
   import os
   os.chdir('C:\mydir')
   from class_def import message

   message_obj = message('Hello')
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

It seems like Python keeps the old version of `class_def.py` and does not import the new one, even though it is saved.

Is this normal behaviour or is Spyder doing something funny?

Comment: I don't get the point. The new __init method takes only 2 arguments, and you are passing three (implicit self, and hello and world). Therefore an error has to arise!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry... Mixed things up a bit. Will edit straight away...

Comment: I have just edited the question. The problem is that the message-class does not change even though I change i class_def.py. So when I use the new definition of message it seems as though pythin "remebers" ther ols definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .pyc file such as class_def.pyc, delete it. 
I'd remove all .pyc files in your working directory and then try again. If that doesn't work, maybe you're not using the module you think you are? To be certain try something like:

```
import myModule
print myModule.__file__ #This will give you the path to the .pyc file your program loaded

#or 
import myModule
import os
print os.path.dirname(myModule.__file__)
```

try those out so you can be certain that you're actually using the file you're modifying. Hope that helps!